# Javascript for loop behaviour outputting the same result each iteration

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, scope

I'll admit I'm a bit of a JS novice, and coming from a PHP background, my idea of scope is clearly different to Javascript's.

```
// There's a date set, so begin processing
var original_date       = new Date($('input#tour_encoded_dates').val());
var date_search_string  = ''; 
var day_limit           = 14;
var timestamp           = '';

// Go forwards day_limit days
for(var i = 0; i < day_limit; i++) {
    timestamp = strtotime('+'+i+' days', original_date);
    calculated_date = new Date(timestamp).format('Y-m-d');
    date_search_string += calculated_date + ' ';
}

console.log(date_search_string);
```

The output from `console.log()` is:

`2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10 2013-10-10`

I would have expected each iteration to increase the date by one day, but they remain the same.

For reference, if I change the final line of the loop to `date_search_string += timestamp + ' ';` the output is as follows:

`1381363200000 1381363286400 1381363372800 1381363459200 1381363545600 1381363632000 1381363718400 1381363804800 1381363891200 1381363977600 1381364064000 1381364150400 1381364236800 1381364323200`

So the issue is clearly with the `calculated_date` variable - right?

Can someone explain the proper way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: what is the code for JS strtotime function?

Comment: what is `day_limit`? is that a number? if it's an array you need to use `day_limit.length` to get the number of stuff in it. is `original_date` inside of `day_limit`?

Comment: @IlyaBursov I've updated the code for clarity.

Comment: what does the date format in `#tour_encoded_dates` look like?

Comment: I just checked your timestamps: http://jsfiddle.net/JrVQL/ - 2013-10-10 is proper result...

Comment: please, give us strtotime code, problem is 99% in it

Comment: I assume you are using 
new Date(milliseconds) //milliseconds since 1970/01/01 is your timestamp correct for that?

Answer (score 2):

There is 86400 (i.e. 1/1000 day), between each timestamp.

You are computing (in `strtotime`) as if timestamps were seconds but they are milliseconds.

Comment: That's it, OP is using [`strtotime` from php.js library](http://phpjs.org/functions/strtotime/), which expects the timestamp in seconds, and multiplies it by 1000, calculate, then divide by 1000 before returning.